# function as ambient module in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

How do I `declare` an ambient `module` that is a `function`?

```
declare module "UUID" {
  (seed?: number): string;
}
```

↑ Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare module "UUID" {
    function uuid(seed?: number): string;
    export = uuid;
}
```

This is some text because code-only answers get flagged for attention!

Comment: Thank you. I've found that also `export default function uuid(...` works.

Comment: Depending on where you put `export default`, this may mean that your UUID module now has a property `.default` on it (or whichever module is immediately surrounding your `export default`).

Comment: Note that `export default` and `export =` are **not the same**

Comment: Yes. While nothing to do with my original question I feel they should be the same/only the ES6-like `export default` should exist. Then, depending on the module format `tsc` is configured to output it could do both, i.e. `module.exports.default = module.exports = function uuid(...`. What would be the drawback there? I'm sure it was considered

Answer (score 3):

You can also use declaration merging, if you need to specify properties on your function.

```
declare module UUID {
    // ...
};
declare function UUID(seed?: number): string;

declare module "UUID" {
    export = UUID;
}
```

None of this is recommended, but is inevitable when converting old js.

Answer (score 0):

Derived from mk.'s answer, I had to arrange things a bit differently to make my compiler happy:

```
declare module 'UUID' {
  namespace UUID {
    // ...
  }

  function UUID(seed?: number): string;

  export = UUID;
}
```

I must say it looks (a bit) more sane to me as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for some reason, exporting a `function` directly as other answers here suggest seems to fail for me. Inside of `declare module`, I found I had to declare

1. A callable interface
2. A variable of that interface’s type

Then I could export the variable. For example, this should work (names changed, please comment if I have typos):

```
declare module 'UUID' {
  interface UuidFunc {
    (seed?: number): string;
  }
  const uuid:UuidFunc;
  exports = uuid;
}
```

## Error

If I try the advice of the other answers, namely:

```
declare module 'UUID' {
  function uuid(seed?:number):string;
  export = uuid;
}
```

and try to consume it with this code, I then get an error:

```
// TS2497: Module ''UUID'' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct
import * as uuid from 'UUID';
```